# Programming Javascript outside Adobe Apps for Adobe Apps

Tags: javascript, pdf, photoshop

I have some great code that produces one sided pdf pages with names and put them in a subfolder (that previously) exists. The problem I have is that this script must be run from within Adobe Acrobat. This is a problem since I want to combine this script with other scripts. Is there a way for me to write this code as jsx I believe it is, so that I can run it from outside Acrobat?

```
var re = /.*\/|\.pdf$/ig;
var filename = this.path.replace(re,"");
var lastPage=this.numPages-1;

{
for ( var i = 0;  i < this.numPages; i++ ) 
this.extractPages
 ({
    nStart: i,
    nEnd: i,
    cPath : "pdf/" + (Number(filename -1) + (i+1)) + ".pdf"
});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

Acrobat JavaScript is not ExtendScript, and Acrobat does not use .jsx files.

If you want to have this function available all the time (but only on your own machine), you could turn it into a function, and install it as an application-level script (aka folder-level script). In this case, every document you open in your Acrobat can make use of this function.

Comment: Very interesting, how can I know where to go from here? Is it still javscript code? Is my code useless? Where can I read about making scripts as application level script.

Comment: Your code is correct Acrobat JavaScript. In addition, may I suggest to have a look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation (which can be downloaded from the Adobe website).